# UItableView + UItabbar

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

UItableView style not changing. I have a tableView controller as one of the tabs of my tab bar controller. I am not able to change the style of UItableView to grouped.

Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new tableViewController and make sure to enable the "also create xib"-like option when giving the tableviewcontroller a name. Copy paste all youre old tablviewcontroller code to the new one and add the xib to the tab window..

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the Tableview's style upon creation. Either in IB or by using the method

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,416) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Comment: I created the table through IB and have tried changing the property to grouped, but to no avail. I mean how finicky is this x-code -- one day it behaves someway and the other day it's the exactly opposite. I have another application which runs fine with the same settings I am trying to get here.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do that in your `UITableViewController`s `-viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
```

**Edit**:

It seems the `style` property is actually read only, so the above won't work.

It looks like the table view controller has to be created with [`-initWithStyle:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007523-CH3-SW2), but I don't know how to do that from Interface Builder. I'm not at my Mac right now, but will have a look later.

**Edit 2**:

Here's what I did in Interface Builder:

1. Add an instance of `UITableView` and set it up as required, including the style
2. Hook up your `UITableViewController` as the delegate and data source of the `UITableView`
3. Connect the `UITableView` with the `view` outlet of the `UITableViewController`. I'm not sure if there is a `tableView` outlet - if there is, then probably connect it with that one instead.

So, basically, instead of letting the `UITableViewController` create its own table view, you provide one in the xib and set up the required connections (delegate, data source, outlet) manually.

Comment: Object cannot be set. Either read only property or no setter found

Comment: Are you working with a UITableViewController or a regular UIViewController?  If it's not a TVC you have to create your own table.

Comment: It's a table View Controller, yes.